# Python : hangman game

Tags: python

```
import random
from typing import List
import sys
words =  [ 'apple', 'tree', 'python', 'bench', 'float' ]
word = random.choice(words) 
guesses= []
f = "Do you want to play hangman?"
a = ["yes","no"]
max_fails = []

def print_word_to_guess(letters: List):
    print("{0}".format(" ".join(letters))) # um _ _ _ _ anzeigen zu lassen und nicht ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_'] 

def input_choice(f:str,a:list[str])->str: # fragt den spieler solang nach einem input bis er yes oder no erhält
    if f in a:
        if f == "yes":
            a = "yes"
        elif f  == "no":
            sys.exit("Ok no it is")
    elif f not in a:
        while f not in a:
            f = input("Invalid answer. Try again")

def shape(word:str,guesses:str)->str: # ist nur für das ersetzten der buchstaben gegen die "_ " da
    for letter in word:
        guesses.append("_ ")

def hangman(word:str,max_fails:int):
    max_fails = int(input("Number of allowed mistakes: "))
    while max_fails> 0: #solang maxfails über 0 ist führt er den code aus
        print(max_fails,"mistakes left")
        guess_str = input("make a guess:")
        for guess in guess_str: #loopt durch die buchstaben in guess (damit ich auch 2 oder mehr buchstaben eingeben kann)

                if guess in word : # tut den buchstaben an die richtige stelle
                    for x in range(0, len(word)):  
                        if word[x] == guess:
                            guesses[x] = guess
                    print_word_to_guess(guesses)

                    if not '_ ' in guesses: 
                        sys.exit(("You won word was:",word))
                        
                else:
                    max_fails -= 1

                    if max_fails == 0:
                        print("You lost :( The word was:",word)

input_choice(input("Do you want to play hangman? [yes / no]"),("yes","no"))  
shape(word,guesses)
hangman(word,max_fails)
```

When I guess multiple letters like "le" it adds another line so like when the word is apple it displays likes this _ _ _ l _ .
_ _ _ l e
But I would like to display it in just on line like _ _ _ l e.
How do I fix that can someone help me :)?

Answer (score 0):

Try just moving the `print_word_to_guesses()`  function to after the loop:

```
import random
from typing import List
import sys
words =  [ 'apple', 'tree', 'python', 'bench', 'float' ]
word = random.choice(words) 
guesses= []
f = "Do you want to play hangman?"
a = ["yes","no"]
max_fails = []

def print_word_to_guess(letters: List):
    print("{0}".format(" ".join(letters))) # um _ _ _ _ anzeigen zu lassen und nicht ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_'] 

def input_choice(f:str,a:list[str])->str: # fragt den spieler solang nach einem input bis er yes oder no erhält
    if f in a:
        if f == "yes":
            a = "yes"
        elif f  == "no":
            sys.exit("Ok no it is")
    elif f not in a:
        while f not in a:
            f = input("Invalid answer. Try again")

def shape(word:str,guesses:str)->str: # ist nur für das ersetzten der buchstaben gegen die "_ " da
    for letter in word:
        guesses.append("_ ")

def hangman(word:str,max_fails:int):
    max_fails = int(input("Number of allowed mistakes: "))
    while max_fails> 0: #solang maxfails über 0 ist führt er den code aus
        print(max_fails,"mistakes left")
        guess_str = input("make a guess:")
        for guess in guess_str: #loopt durch die buchstaben in guess (damit ich auch 2 oder mehr buchstaben eingeben kann)

                if guess in word : # tut den buchstaben an die richtige stelle
                    for x in range(0, len(word)):  
                        if word[x] == guess:
                            guesses[x] = guess

                    if not '_ ' in guesses: 
                        sys.exit(("You won word was:",word))
                        
                else:
                    max_fails -= 1

                    if max_fails == 0:
                        print("You lost :( The word was:",word)
        print_word_to_guess(guesses)

input_choice(input("Do you want to play hangman? [yes / no]"),("yes","no"))  
shape(word,guesses)
hangman(word,max_fails)
```

Comment: damn I tried that but in the wrong line :D anyways thanks^^